# Как сделать общий hover для кнопки с треугольником

Tags: css, button, hover, border

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на кнопку, она меняла цвет своего border'a и чтобы тоже самое проделывала стрелка, которая находится в этой кнопке(при наведении на саму кнопку). У меня получилось сделать только так чтобы при наведении на кнопку, она меняла цвет своего border'a, но стрелка при этом не меняет свой цвет и только при наведении на стрелку она меняет свой цвет.
Вот куски кода HTML:
 `<button class="slider-swap" id="left-head"><span id="left-arr"></span></button>`

Кусок кода CSS:

```
.slider-swap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
}
#left-arr {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-right: 20px solid #fff;
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
bottom: 28px;
left: 28px;
```

}

```
#left-arr:hover {
border-right: 20px solid #00c0ff;
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
```

}

```
.slider-swap:hover {
border: 1px solid #00c0ff;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ховер иконки срабатывал, нужно эти стили в CSS применять не для ховера на эту иконку, а для ховера на весь блок:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.slider-swap {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

#left-arr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid #fff;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 28px;
}

.slider-swap:hover #left-arr {
  border-right-color: #00c0ff;
}

.slider-swap:hover {
  border-color: #00c0ff;
}
```

```html
<button class="slider-swap" id="left-head"><span id="left-arr"></span></button>
```